# Unable to call function from extension

Tags: swift, swift3

I am trying to append a string using `extension` in swift but its throwing error like `"value of type 'String' has no member addString "`

```
import UIKit

var str = "Hello, playground"

var str2 = str.addString(" Appending String ...")

extension String {
    mutating func addString(str:String) {
        self = self+str
    }
}
```

Comment: Define the method *before* using it?

Comment: why would you make an extension to append a string? You can already do this by just using "+".

Comment: Put your extension above. And shouldn't it be `str.addString(str:"Appending String ...");` (missing the introduction of the param), and there is no return, no? So no `var str2 =`.

Comment: @Larme Thanks for your help and now its working..just started learning swift so confusion..

Comment: @MartinR i don't know that i need to define method before using it..I taught it can be same as java :)  Thanks for help..

Comment: @Martheli  yeah i know to append directly using + but just trying the extension..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem 1: The method must be defined before it can be used in a global scope.

```
var str = "Hello, playground"

extension String{
    mutating func addString(str:String)
    {
        self = self + str
    }
}

var str2 = str.addString(" Appending String ...")
```

Problem 2: The method you defined doesn't match how you use it. Your `addString(str:)` works like this.

```
str.addString(str: " Appending String ...")
var str2 = str
```

To make `addString(_:)` match your use it needs to be.

```
extension String {
    func addString(_ str: String) -> String
    {
        return self + str
    }
}

var str2 = str.addString(" Appending String ...")
```